# How to total number of channel accesses

Tags: mysql, select, count, sum

I am trying to set up a few queries for a MySQL database of tables containing details of video channels and subscribers to these channels. One of the queries attempts to list all the existing channels and how many times each channel has been accessed by any of the subscribers. In this query I am not interested which subscriber has accessed a channel but simply the list of all channels and TOTAL times each channel has ever been accessed. It probably is a very simple query, but I am just starting playing with databases, so please don't blast me. 
For this I am using two of tables created (in short) with:

```
CREATE TABLE channels (channel_id, channel_name, channel_descr);

CREATE TABLE channel_accesses (channel_id, subscriber_id, access_date, num_of_accesses);
```

I have tried to select all channel_ids and names from the 'channels' table and `count()` or `sum()` the `num_of_accesses` in `channel_access` but I come up with some funny results as I actually didn't know how to put the two together properly. In table `channel_accesses`, `num_of_accesses` stores how many times a subscriber has accessed a particular channel. So what I need is to total somehow how many times a channel was accessed by any of the subscribers (sorry, I think I repeated myself here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple query you need:

First join the two table in the `FROM` clause, using the foreign key column (`channel_id`). We need to use `LEFT JOIN` so all channels appear in the result set, even those with no subscribers and accesses at all.:

```
FROM
    channels AS c
  LEFT JOIN 
    channel_accesses AS ca
      ON ca.channel_id = c.channel_id
```

Then we group by the primary key of `channels` because we want a result for every channel:

```
GROUP BY
    c.channel_id, c.channel_name
```

Finally, we can `SELECT` the columns we want from `channels` and the aggregate (`SUM` of `num_of_accesses`). The `COALESCE()` function is added so we get 0s instead of nulls for channels without subscribers:

```
SELECT 
    c.channel_id, 
    c.channel_name,
    COALESCE(SUM(ca.num_of_accesses), 0) AS total_num_of_accesses
FROM 
    channels AS c
  LEFT JOIN 
    channel_accesses AS ca
      ON ca.channel_id = c.channel_id
GROUP BY
    c.channel_id, c.channel_name ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, y/cube, for the detailed and easy to understand explanation. That's exactly what I needed in terms of both type of explanation and the suggested solution itself. Kind of encouraging for me too, as I was not far from this myself with a few exceptions that threw my results all over the place. Many thanks again!

Comment: ++ for your answer. Sorry, not enough reputation on my side to be able to vote up.